# Multitouch UITouches after SwiftUI Drag

Tags: swiftui, uikit, gesture, uitouch, uiviewrepresentable

I'm implementing a SwiftUI control over a UIView's drawing surface. Often you are doing both at the same time. Problem is that starting with the SwiftUI control will block the UIKit's UITouch(s). And yet, it works when you start with the UITouch first and then the SwiftUI control.

Here is the example code:

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    @GestureState private var touchXY: CGPoint = .zero
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TouchRepresentable()
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .frame(width: 128, height: 128)
                .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                    .updating($touchXY) { (value, touchXY, _) in touchXY = value.location})
                .onChange(of: touchXY) {
                    print(String(format:"SwiftUI(%.2g,%.2g)", $0.x,$0.y), terminator: " ") }
            //.allowsHitTesting(true) no difference
        }
    }
}
struct TouchRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias Context = UIViewRepresentableContext<TouchRepresentable>
    public func makeUIView(context: Context) -> TouchView { return TouchView() }
    public func updateUIView(_ uiView: TouchView, context: Context) {}
}
class TouchView: UIView, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func updateTouches(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: nil)
            print(String(format: "UIKit(%g,%g) ", round(location.x), round(location.y)), terminator: " ") }
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) { updateTouches(touches, with: event) }
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) { updateTouches(touches, with: event) }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) { updateTouches(touches, with: event) }
    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) { updateTouches(touches, with: event) }
}
```

Because this is multitouch, you need to test on a real device.

Sequence A:

1. finger 1 starts dragging outside of red square (UIKit)
2. finger 2 simultaneously drags inside of red square (SwiftUI)

=> Console shows *both* UIKit and SwiftUI touch positions

Sequence B:

1. finger 1 starts dragging inside of red square (SwiftUI)
2. finger 2 simultaneously drags outside of red square (UIKit)

=> Console shows *only* SwiftUI touch positions

Would like to get both positions in Sequence B.